# An orthonormal basis in a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let an orthonormal basis of $\Bbb{R}^n$ be $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$, and $U$ be a subspace in $\Bbb{R}^n$. Can we construct the orthonormal basis of $U$ by taking randomly from $\{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$?
If possible, would you prove it?

Comment: Look up Gram-Schmidt algorithm.

Comment: @Chrystomath What if no $e_i$ belongs to $I$?

Comment: The subspace $U$ must be generated from some vectors $u_1,\ldots,u_k$. Apply GS to these.

Comment: Thanks. Is {u_1,...,u_k} a subset of {e_1,...,e_n}?

Comment: No, unless $U$ is generated by some axes of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 2):

In general, no, it is *not* possible. Take $n=2$, let $\{e_1,e_2\}$ be the standard basis of $\Bbb R^2$ and let $U=\{(x,x)\mid x\in\Bbb R\}$. Then no subset of $\{e_1,e_2\}$ is a basis of $U$, since neither $e_1\in U$ nor $e_2\in U$.